# Computing the size of automorphism groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If I have the group $G = \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, then what is the size of $\textrm{Aut}(G)$ ?

In my abstract algebra class, it was not yet proven that the groups $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ for $p$ prime are isomorphic to the $n\times n$ invertible matrices under $\mathbb{F}_p$. We are given the result that, "if $f:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism with $G=\langle K\rangle$, then $f$ is determined by where it takes the members of $K$". I know that the answer is $168$ from the linear algebra method of counting the linearly independent vectors, but I can't figure it out with what I am given.

Comment: You can just carry out the same argument in the group without reference to linear algebra.

Comment: Hint: The group is 'totally symmetric' in the sense that any non-identity element can be mapped to any other by an automorphism. However, automorphism must preserve relative membership in subgroups, as well as having the property of mapping generators to generators. So pick on an arbitrary generating set and count how many places you can map it. (order of gens matters!)

Comment: The claim "*the groups $\mathbb{Z}_p^n$ for $p$ prime are isomorphic to the $n\times n$ invertible matrices under $\mathbb{F}_p$*" is wrong, but "*the groups $Aut(\mathbb{Z}_p^n)$ for $p$ prime are isomorphic to the $n\times n$ invertible matrices under $\mathbb{F}_p$*" is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not hard to find $|Aut(G)|$ for the elementary abelian $2$-groups.

Consider a generating set for $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\{a,b,c\}$.

Note that $a$ can be mapped by an automorphism to any of the 7 non-identity elements. Once you decide where $a$ goes, $b$ has 6 remaining places it can go.

Now that both $a$ and $b$ are assigned, their product $ab$ is also assigned (preservation of relative subgroup membership). This $c$ has only 4 places it can go. Thus gives $7\cdot 6\cdot 4=168$ possibilities.

Comment: I guess that to get full marks for a solution you would need to justify the fact that all of these $168$ possibilities really do define an automorphism.

Comment: @DerekHolt: That follows easily from the elementary fact that automorphisms map generators to generators (and hence minimum size generating sets to minimum size generating sets). All 28 size 3 gen sets for $G$ give the same presentation for $G$ up to a renaming of elements.